# Numerically Evaluating Functions Like $I(x)=(\int_0^xf(x^\prime)\mathrm{d}x^\prime)/x$ near $x=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, singularity

Like the title says, I'm interested in numerically evaluating the function
$$I(x)=\frac{\int_0^xf(x^\prime)\mathrm{d}x^\prime}{x}$$
where $f(x^\prime)$ is given by the user as sampled points and is greater than zero at $x=0$ so that this function evaluates to a finite value.  The trouble is that near $x=0$ both the numerator and denominator become small and lead to trouble, especially when you are actually at $x=0$.

I could obviously Taylor expand in this region, but using a piecewise expression feels like a kluge and means I can't fully take advantage of vectorized math to speed things up due to the if-statement.

**Is there some global way of re-writing this function that makes it safe for numerical evaluation near $x=0$?**

Comment: Taylor expansion of $F=\int f$ should give good approximations. The first order approximation gives $f(0)$

Comment: Also, is Taylor expansion not „vectorizable“ (what is the programming context to your question?)

Comment: Could you expand on "$f(x′)$ is given by the user as sampled points"? So it means you have only the values $f(k\Delta x)$ available, and would for example integrate the quadratic interpolation polynomial using the first three points for the first two intervals?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, by not vectorizable I mean that if I Taylor expand then my code would look like 

`def I(x):
    if(x<epsilon):
        do_something(x)
    else:
        do_something_else(x)`

The problem is that I want to evaluate $I(x)$ between $10^4$ and $10^6$ times and care about performance for my application so the if statement means I can't take advantage of vectorized operations acting over the array of $x$ in something like numpy.  That's easily a factor of three or more in execution time.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, that's just a low-level detail that maybe I shouldn't have emphasized the way I did.  It's exactly what you said where I have the values of the function at $x=k\Delta x$ for non-negative integers $k$.  Just off the top of my head I would be using numpy's implementation of the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: I would question your premise. If I compute $x/x$ for small real numbers $x$, I get exactly $1$ even in floating point arithmetic. As long as the numerator and denominator are computed accurately, I don't believe evaluating this quotient is as problematic as you say it is. (For incredibly small numbers $x$ you may have a problem if $x$ becomes subnormal, but these are truly tiny numbers in double precision arithmetic.)

Comment: I imagine if you try direct evaluation of the integral using samples of a known analytic function with small $x$ you'll find the rounding errors pale in comparison to the discretization errors of e.g. the trapezoid rule.

Comment: @ElectronsAndStuff I am still confused: Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt$. Then $F(0)=0$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$ so Taylor expansion at $0$ gives that $F$ behaves like $$F(x)\sim x f(0)+\frac{x^2}2 f'(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!} f''(0)+\dots$$ i.e. $I$ behaves like $$I(x)\sim f(0)+\frac{x}2 f'(0)+\frac{x^2}6 f''(0)+\dots,$$ cutting off after one term for example leads to $I(x)\approx f(0)$, cutting off after two terms leads to $I(x)\approx f(0)+\frac{x}2 f'(0)$ and so on. Where does $\varepsilon$ come in in this idea?

Comment: Also, as far as I am aware, "for loops vs. vectorization" does not change the complexity of the program so I am not sure that, given that you might perform some tasks of much higher complexity than evaluating this function, this will make a big difference on run time

Comment: Sure the Taylor expansion method works for small $x$, but what about when $x=10$?  What about when $x=1e5$?  You need to choose a small value, $\epsilon$ as your threshold for when to Taylor expand and when to directly evaluate the function.

I don't care about asymptotics.  The function is a computational kernel that needs to be run up to $10^6$ times in a performant manner.  The constants matter.  Vectorized vs non-vectorized makes a huge difference in this area and branching code should be avoided.  This is why, for instance, graphics code run in parallel doesn't use if-statements.

Comment: @ElectronsAndStuff I think in this case the question might be a better fit for the computer science StackExchange (or maybe StackOverflow), as it is rather about optimization „for the computer“ rather than theoretical optimization

Comment: @ElectronsAndStuff Another question: If you evaluate $I$ at many different $x$, then why don't you "a priori" separate all $x>\varepsilon$ and all $x<\varepsilon$ and then use "direct evaluation" (what does that mean? numerical integration?) for large $x$ and Taylor for small $x$ separately?

Comment: Yeah, that's almost what I ended up implementing.  I care only about evaluating $I(x)$ at a set of evenly spaced points on the interval $[0, x_0]$.  I don't run a comparison on each point to see if there's a danger of dividing by zero, but I do the direct evaluation anyways and let the division return "inf" for the first point and then fix it afterwords.  That way there's only a small constant overhead.  I still feel like there should be a more elegant way where you just re-write the integral in a global way (read: not Taylor expansion) to make the false singularity go away.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the MVT for integrals to get that
$$\int_0^x f(x')\mathrm{d}x'=xf(c)$$
For some $c \in (0,x)$. This guarentees that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} I(x)=f(0)$$
If $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The assumption of continuity of $f$ is needed for the first statement (the mean-value theorem for integrals).

Comment: Thanks!  That's an interesting point.  I guess the difficulty then lies in finding $c(x)$ since in general the point will change for each different interval you use.

Comment: @JohnBentin I wanted to express that continuity is necessary for the whole process with "If $f$ is continuous." at the end. But I'm going to put it to the front to make it clear.